# Connection between Functional Analysis and Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, functional-analysis, soft-question

From perusing MathOverflow, I’ve gotten the impression that functional analysis and combinatorics are somehow related. I am currently an avid fan of combinatorics, but have yet to study functional analysis, and to my current knowledge don’t see why this would be the case.

Originally, I saw a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes#comment36789_7182https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7155/famous-mathematical-quotes%23comment36789_7182) saying that the two subjects were connected, and just thought it was a silly joke. However, looking into it, I’ve noticed that are a least a few big mathematicians who have focused on both of these fields. Namely, I am aware that both Timothy Gowers and Gian-Carlo Rota began with functional analysis, and transitioned to combinatorics. Is this simply coincidence, or is there some natural relation between these two particular fields?

Comment: That some mathematicians focused on both those topics does not necessarily mean that they are actually related. I would like to see an example for such a relation.

Comment: I would rather think that someone saying that two areas of mathematics are not connect was the silly joke. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36824/applications-of-measure-integration-and-banach-spaces-to-combinatorics) there are some examples in the case of combinatorics and functional analysis.